# Facebook login authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I have a option in my web page such that, on-clicking a button, Facebook login authentication dialog will be poped up as explained in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#server-side-flow. I am using JavaScript SDK (FB.api) for this.

So on users successful authentication and app authorization, I will retrieve an **ACCESS TOKEN for that particular user** from the response. To avoid token expiration, I am using OFFLINE_ACCESS. Finally the token is saved in my local database and a **cron job will use this token periodically** to read users Facebook datas.

My problem is, as Facebook is going to **deprecate the offline_access**, is there any other way to have unique ACCESS TOKEN for a user (with out expiration time), such that the users will approve my app once and the cron job will use their token to read data on regular basis.

From this link: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal I found that we can only extend the token expiration time.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: From May 1st when offline_access is deprecated, you will have to get your users to login every 60 days to enable you to scrape their data in this way. This is specifically to prevent "fire-and-forget" applications from receiving the offline_access permissions once and then having total access forever more.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the quick response. "From May 1st offline_access is deprecated". But even now my ACCESS TOKEN expires periodically (even after using offline access). Why is it so? For example, say today an users is authenticating my app. Is there any way to avoid token expiration until May 1st ?